# HTML Outlook Calendar Embed

Tags: html, css, outlook, embed

I should embed an outlook calendar in my website, but when I load the page, it makes me download it instead embed in webpage.
Do you know why?
This is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<style unselectable="on">
#wrap {
width:1000px;
height:900px;
padding:0;
position:relative;
left:0px;
top:0px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#frame {
width:1000px;
height:900px;
position:relative;
left:0px;
top:0px;
}
#frame {
-ms-zoom:0.7;
}
</style>
<div id="wrap" unselectable="on">
    <iframe id="frame" src="http://link.it/blablabla/ical.ics"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much

Comment: You are not calling a web page you are calling a particular files.that's why.

Comment: Well you need to call a page with certain parameters, check out this [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/ocalendar-oaddtask/how-to-embed-a-calendar-using-the-new-outlookcom/d2efa06b-37a3-434f-866c-a192641aa493) for more information.

Comment: @Nicolas THe websiite programmer that has provided me the URL of this calendar, has given to me the ics file... How I have to do?

Comment: when you log in into your calendar, click on share, then use the getLink options and select event. And choose the one for HTML. copy the link and paste it into your src attributes of your iframe.